# Why Microsoft Cognitive doesn't return every OCR field?

Tags: ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to read MRZ zone from passports with Microsoft Cognitive Vision but is impossible. It never returns that field, when (I guess) is the easiest field of all...

An example:

[image: Ukrainian Passport]

Does anyone knows why it doesn't return that field? Has Cognitive a limit of fields? Do I need to include any param to increase the number of fields to return? Is there any valid alternative that will return that field (I've tried Amazon Rekognition but only returns 50 fields)

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your example with both Computer Vision API's [**OCR**](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc) and Computer Vision API's [**Recognize Text**](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200) and I can confirm that it doesn't return the MRZ zone in the OCR, but it works perfectly with Recognize Text!

Here's the result of using **OCR**:

```
{
  "language": "en",
  "orientation": "Up",
  "textAngle": 0.0,
  "regions": [{
    "boundingBox": "426,113,815,25",
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": "426,113,104,24",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "426,113,49,24",
        "text": "Tun/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "482,113,48,24",
        "text": "Type"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "590,113,651,25",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "590,113,41,22",
        "text": "KOA"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "636,113,106,24",
        "text": "mepxaBM/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "746,113,145,25",
        "text": "qountrycode"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "914,113,71,24",
        "text": "HOMep"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "992,113,111,24",
        "text": "nacnopTa/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "1108,113,94,24",
        "text": "Passport"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "1206,113,35,19",
        "text": "No."
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "boundingBox": "220,151,168,61",
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": "222,151,165,24",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "222,151,165,24",
        "text": "nAcnOPT"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "220,187,168,25",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "220,187,168,25",
        "text": "PASSPORT"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "boundingBox": "426,144,410,318",
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": "428,144,18,29",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "428,144,18,29",
        "text": "p"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "592,145,69,29",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "592,145,69,29",
        "text": "UKR"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "426,184,214,25",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "426,185,114,24",
        "text": "npi3Bv1Lue/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "545,184,95,20",
        "text": "Surname"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "429,212,407,36",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "429,212,407,36",
        "text": "TKAHEHKO/TKACHENKO"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "426,255,195,24",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "426,255,51,24",
        "text": "1M'\"/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "483,255,58,20",
        "text": "Given"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "548,256,73,19",
        "text": "Names"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "429,286,321,36",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "429,286,321,36",
        "text": "MAP'AHA/MARIANA"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "426,328,284,24",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "426,328,164,24",
        "text": "rPOMaARHCTBO/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "596,328,114,23",
        "text": "Nationality"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "430,352,314,41",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "430,352,314,41",
        "text": "YKPAiHA/UKRAINE"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "426,398,339,24",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "426,398,53,23",
        "text": "LlaTa"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "486,398,143,24",
        "text": "HaPOAXeHHA/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "634,398,49,20",
        "text": "Date"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "689,398,23,20",
        "text": "of"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "715,398,50,20",
        "text": "birth"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "428,427,256,35",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "428,428,40,29",
        "text": "-24"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "482,427,148,35",
        "text": "CEP/AUG"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "639,427,45,30",
        "text": "91"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "boundingBox": "901,143,175,317",
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": "908,143,168,33",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "908,143,168,33",
        "text": "xxoooooo"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "914,397,118,21",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "914,397,100,21",
        "text": "3anncNQ/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "1019,398,13,19",
        "text": "R"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "901,425,131,35",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "901,425,131,35",
        "text": "123456"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "boundingBox": "426,469,521,27",
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": "426,469,521,27",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "426,470,72,24",
        "text": "CTaTb/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "503,470,42,20",
        "text": "Sex"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "592,470,63,23",
        "text": "Micue"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "662,470,206,26",
        "text": "HaponxeHH9/P/ace"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "874,470,23,20",
        "text": "of"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "900,469,47,21",
        "text": "birth"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "boundingBox": "426,492,388,113",
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": "432,492,382,42",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "432,498,66,36",
        "text": ">K/F"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "595,499,36,31",
        "text": "M."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "646,492,168,41",
        "text": "KVliB/UKR"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "426,541,278,24",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "426,541,53,23",
        "text": "AaTa"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "486,541,78,24",
        "text": "unaqi/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "569,541,49,19",
        "text": "Date"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "624,541,23,20",
        "text": "of"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "650,541,54,20",
        "text": "issue"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "430,569,243,36",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "430,570,39,30",
        "text": "25"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "484,569,138,36",
        "text": "BEP/SEP"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "638,569,35,29",
        "text": "13"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "boundingBox": "914,538,275,62",
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": "914,538,275,33",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "914,540,71,25",
        "text": "OpraH,"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "1031,538,158,33",
        "text": "BHAaB(Authgri"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "914,568,89,32",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "914,568,89,32",
        "text": "xxxx"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "boundingBox": "76,606,1261,312",
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": "426,606,911,35",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "426,613,53,25",
        "text": "AaTa"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "485,613,116,19",
        "text": "aaKil-lHeHHfl"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "608,617,72,20",
        "text": "CTPOKY"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "685,613,35,24",
        "text": "Aii/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "726,613,49,19",
        "text": "Date"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "780,613,91,24",
        "text": "ofexpiry"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "914,613,118,26",
        "text": "[liannc,ppe"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "1077,606,129,31",
        "text": "WilKä/hiöldé"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "1248,613,89,28",
        "text": "qtlåtåre"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "431,644,243,37",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "431,645,39,30",
        "text": "25"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "485,644,138,37",
        "text": "BEP/SEP"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": "636,644,38,29",
        "text": "23"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": "76,885,567,33",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": "76,885,567,33",
        "text": "XXOOOOOO<OUKR9108242"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Here's the result of using **Recognize Text**:

```
{
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "recognitionResult": {
    "lines": [{
      "boundingBox": [422, 64, 1090, 62, 1091, 110, 423, 112],
      "text": "LA yKPAIHA & UKRAINE",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [419, 68, 456, 67, 454, 111, 418, 110],
        "text": "LA"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [478, 67, 702, 64, 701, 113, 477, 111],
        "text": "yKPAIHA"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [732, 64, 760, 64, 760, 113, 732, 113],
        "text": "&"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [802, 64, 1029, 64, 1030, 110, 802, 113],
        "text": "UKRAINE"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [424, 111, 536, 112, 535, 138, 423, 136],
      "text": "Tun/ Type",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [425, 112, 478, 112, 479, 138, 426, 138],
        "text": "Tun/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [478, 112, 531, 114, 532, 137, 479, 138],
        "text": "Type"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [583, 111, 1241, 110, 1242, 138, 584, 138],
      "text": "KoA nepxaBu/ Country code Homep nacnopTa/ Passport No.",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [584, 111, 631, 112, 631, 139, 584, 139],
        "text": "KoA"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [633, 112, 744, 113, 744, 138, 633, 139],
        "text": "nepxaBu/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [744, 113, 832, 113, 832, 138, 744, 138],
        "text": "Country"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [832, 113, 888, 113, 888, 138, 832, 138],
        "text": "code"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [909, 113, 986, 113, 987, 138, 909, 138],
        "text": "Homep"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [986, 113, 1106, 112, 1107, 138, 987, 138],
        "text": "nacnopTa/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1105, 112, 1207, 111, 1208, 138, 1105, 138],
        "text": "Passport"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1201, 111, 1248, 111, 1249, 139, 1202, 138],
        "text": "No."
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [66, 152, 171, 157, 171, 206, 68, 207],
      "text": "-O",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [56, 151, 138, 155, 136, 209, 53, 205],
        "text": "-O"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [213, 142, 397, 139, 398, 183, 213, 186],
      "text": "nAcnOPT",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [213, 143, 393, 141, 393, 184, 215, 187],
        "text": "nAcnOPT"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [407, 146, 480, 148, 479, 172, 407, 174],
      "text": "P",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [426, 146, 445, 147, 444, 175, 425, 174],
        "text": "P"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [583, 144, 685, 144, 684, 174, 582, 173],
      "text": "UKR",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [588, 145, 654, 147, 655, 173, 589, 175],
        "text": "UKR"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [214, 176, 402, 180, 401, 224, 213, 220],
      "text": "PASSPORT",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [214, 179, 392, 183, 392, 223, 218, 222],
        "text": "PASSPORT"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [900, 136, 1085, 137, 1084, 181, 899, 180],
      "text": "XX000000",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [906, 138, 1080, 139, 1077, 182, 911, 181],
        "text": "XX000000"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [399, 183, 646, 182, 647, 207, 400, 208],
      "text": "npi3BNLLle/ Surname",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [422, 185, 542, 184, 541, 209, 421, 208],
        "text": "npi3BNLLle/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [546, 184, 641, 184, 641, 208, 546, 209],
        "text": "Surname"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [423, 210, 835, 207, 836, 244, 424, 247],
      "text": "TKAYEHKO/TKACHENKO",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [429, 211, 835, 208, 835, 244, 430, 247],
        "text": "TKAYEHKO/TKACHENKO"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [422, 251, 630, 253, 629, 279, 421, 278],
      "text": "IM's/ Given Names",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [419, 254, 480, 253, 480, 279, 420, 279],
        "text": "IM's/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [483, 253, 542, 253, 542, 280, 483, 279],
        "text": "Given"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [545, 253, 625, 255, 624, 280, 545, 280],
        "text": "Names"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [424, 275, 929, 286, 928, 339, 423, 328],
      "text": "MAP'AHA/MARIANA",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [422, 285, 744, 285, 746, 324, 424, 321],
        "text": "MAP'AHA/MARIANA"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [424, 325, 720, 324, 721, 352, 425, 353],
      "text": "poManAHCTBO/ Nationality",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [435, 328, 592, 326, 592, 353, 435, 352],
        "text": "poManAHCTBO/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [592, 326, 707, 326, 706, 353, 592, 353],
        "text": "Nationality"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [423, 347, 914, 332, 916, 383, 425, 398],
      "text": "yKPAIHA/UKRAINEAIN",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [429, 355, 868, 338, 871, 386, 431, 391],
        "text": "yKPAIHA/UKRAINEAIN"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [426, 384, 896, 394, 895, 445, 425, 435],
      "text": "AaTa HapoAxeHHA/ Date of birth",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [424, 398, 482, 398, 482, 423, 424, 425],
        "text": "AaTa"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [480, 398, 633, 398, 632, 422, 480, 423],
        "text": "HapoAxeHHA/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [633, 398, 685, 397, 684, 425, 632, 422],
        "text": "Date"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [687, 397, 715, 397, 715, 427, 686, 425],
        "text": "of"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [712, 397, 762, 396, 761, 430, 711, 426],
        "text": "birth"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [429, 424, 702, 421, 703, 459, 429, 462],
      "text": "24 CEP/AUG 91",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [425, 425, 469, 425, 470, 461, 426, 460],
        "text": "24"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [481, 425, 630, 425, 630, 460, 481, 462],
        "text": "CEP/AUG"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [639, 425, 686, 425, 685, 457, 639, 459],
        "text": "91"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [906, 394, 1123, 393, 1124, 422, 907, 423],
      "text": "3annc No/ Record No.",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [913, 397, 980, 395, 980, 422, 913, 424],
        "text": "3annc"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [978, 395, 1018, 394, 1018, 422, 978, 422],
        "text": "No/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1014, 394, 1089, 395, 1088, 423, 1014, 422],
        "text": "Record"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1089, 395, 1130, 397, 1129, 424, 1088, 423],
        "text": "No."
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [902, 415, 1119, 416, 1118, 461, 901, 459],
      "text": "1234567890",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [905, 416, 1119, 418, 1117, 461, 908, 461],
        "text": "1234567890"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [426, 468, 568, 466, 569, 492, 426, 493],
      "text": "CTaTb/ Sex",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [425, 468, 501, 469, 501, 494, 426, 493],
        "text": "CTaTb/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [504, 469, 545, 469, 543, 492, 504, 494],
        "text": "Sex"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [573, 467, 954, 467, 954, 493, 574, 494],
      "text": "Micue HaponxeHHa/ Place of birth",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [588, 470, 656, 470, 656, 495, 588, 494],
        "text": "Micue"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [658, 470, 808, 469, 808, 495, 658, 495],
        "text": "HaponxeHHa/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [808, 469, 868, 468, 868, 495, 808, 495],
        "text": "Place"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [873, 468, 899, 468, 899, 495, 873, 495],
        "text": "of"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [897, 468, 946, 468, 946, 495, 897, 495],
        "text": "birth"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [428, 494, 507, 496, 506, 534, 433, 532],
      "text": "XX/F",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [431, 494, 499, 496, 498, 534, 430, 532],
        "text": "XX/F"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [580, 489, 812, 492, 811, 537, 579, 534],
      "text": "M. KNIB/UKR",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [586, 492, 641, 492, 643, 535, 590, 534],
        "text": "M."
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [638, 492, 810, 493, 809, 538, 641, 535],
        "text": "KNIB/UKR"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [428, 538, 708, 539, 707, 565, 427, 564],
      "text": "LaTa BuAayi/ Date of issue",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [426, 541, 480, 540, 481, 565, 427, 564],
        "text": "LaTa"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [482, 540, 565, 540, 566, 565, 483, 565],
        "text": "BuAayi/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [568, 540, 618, 539, 619, 565, 569, 565],
        "text": "Date"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [623, 539, 649, 539, 649, 565, 623, 565],
        "text": "of"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [645, 539, 704, 539, 703, 565, 645, 565],
        "text": "issue"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [429, 561, 678, 564, 678, 608, 428, 605],
      "text": "25 BEP/SEP 13",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [423, 563, 475, 563, 476, 606, 425, 607],
        "text": "25"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [477, 563, 625, 564, 625, 608, 479, 606],
        "text": "BEP/SEP"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [631, 564, 679, 565, 679, 609, 631, 608],
        "text": "13"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [913, 536, 1207, 537, 1206, 568, 912, 567],
      "text": "OpraH, Lilo BunaB/ Authority",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [912, 540, 992, 540, 992, 565, 913, 565],
        "text": "OpraH,"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [989, 540, 1026, 540, 1026, 565, 989, 565],
        "text": "Lilo"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1028, 539, 1109, 539, 1108, 567, 1028, 565],
        "text": "BunaB/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1108, 539, 1205, 538, 1204, 569, 1107, 567],
        "text": "Authority"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [909, 565, 1026, 568, 1025, 601, 908, 598],
      "text": "XXXX",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [914, 567, 1001, 569, 1001, 599, 915, 600],
        "text": "XXXX"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [422, 611, 1336, 610, 1337, 637, 423, 638],
      "text": "LaTa 3akiHyeHHA CTpoky Ail/ Date of expiry finnnc npen ABHuka/ Holder's signature",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [425, 613, 479, 613, 480, 637, 425, 637],
        "text": "LaTa"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [484, 613, 602, 613, 602, 638, 484, 637],
        "text": "3akiHyeHHA"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [605, 613, 681, 612, 681, 639, 605, 638],
        "text": "CTpoky"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [683, 612, 722, 612, 722, 639, 683, 639],
        "text": "Ail/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [725, 612, 775, 612, 775, 639, 725, 639],
        "text": "Date"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [780, 612, 806, 612, 805, 639, 780, 639],
        "text": "of"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [804, 612, 871, 612, 870, 639, 804, 639],
        "text": "expiry"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [909, 612, 988, 612, 987, 639, 908, 639],
        "text": "finnnc"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [989, 612, 1046, 611, 1044, 639, 988, 639],
        "text": "npen"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1052, 611, 1141, 611, 1140, 638, 1050, 639],
        "text": "ABHuka/"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1141, 611, 1235, 611, 1234, 638, 1140, 638],
        "text": "Holder's"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1237, 611, 1337, 611, 1335, 637, 1235, 638],
        "text": "signature"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [427, 638, 677, 637, 678, 681, 428, 683],
      "text": "25 BEP/SEP 23",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [426, 641, 475, 640, 477, 683, 429, 684],
        "text": "25"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [477, 639, 625, 638, 625, 681, 480, 683],
        "text": "BEP/SEP"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [630, 638, 679, 639, 679, 682, 631, 681],
        "text": "23"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [69, 805, 891, 803, 892, 845, 70, 846],
      "text": "P<UKRTKACHENKO< <MARIANA< < < < <",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [70, 809, 498, 811, 499, 847, 72, 844],
        "text": "P<UKRTKACHENKO<"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [503, 811, 759, 808, 759, 846, 504, 847],
        "text": "<MARIANA<"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [763, 808, 787, 807, 788, 846, 764, 846],
        "text": "<"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [791, 807, 815, 806, 816, 846, 792, 846],
        "text": "<"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [822, 806, 845, 806, 846, 845, 823, 846],
        "text": "<"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [850, 806, 874, 805, 874, 845, 851, 845],
        "text": "<"
      }]
    }, {
      "boundingBox": [70, 876, 1346, 877, 1346, 926, 69, 925],
      "text": "XX000000<OUKR9108242F23092571234567890< < < <70",
      "words": [{
        "boundingBox": [71, 879, 1198, 878, 1197, 927, 71, 926],
        "text": "XX000000<OUKR9108242F23092571234567890<"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1195, 878, 1226, 878, 1225, 927, 1194, 927],
        "text": "<"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1226, 878, 1257, 878, 1256, 927, 1225, 927],
        "text": "<"
      }, {
        "boundingBox": [1254, 878, 1346, 877, 1345, 927, 1253, 927],
        "text": "<70"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

So, try using Computer Vision API's [Recognize Text](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200) then [Get Recognize Text Operation Result](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2cf1154055056008f201) to get the result of the operation.